# What is the advantage of having a high CP Pokemon (such as one with CP 3000)?

Tags: pokemon-go

Let's say if we power up a Pokemon to a CP of 3000, what is the advantage of having it?

Because I thought having a high CP Pokemon is mainly to be more powerful if it stays at a gym, but isn't it true that another player can just repeat a fight again and again, to make the Prestige point lower and lower each time, and eventually bring it to 0, and kick the original Pokemon out?

So, if a player has a Pokemon with CP of 1200, he or she can kick out the Pokemon at a gym with a CP of 3000. Or, if the gym has 3 or even 6 Pokemons, each with a CP of 2000, if the player keeps on fighting, eventually he or she can occupy the gym?

Or, what if it is a team of 5 or 7 people, who all go to a gym, and then each person just need to fight and bring down the Prestige point by 2500 point (per person), and then bring down as many as 17500 Prestige point of a gym and kick all Pokemons out and occupy the gym?

(So if there is a Pokemon with CP 3000 at a gym, and a player who has a Pokemon of CP 1000, it won't be the case that it is very difficult or close to impossible that he or she can kick out the 3000 CP Pokemon?  The player just need to repeat fighting to bring the Prestige to 0 and kick out that CP 3000 Pokemon?)

Comment: It compensates for other things in (your?) life that's not over 9000.

Comment: because I thought if it is like: a CP 1000 Pokemon can almost never defeat a CP 3000 Pokemon unless by extreme luck, and a CP 2000 may defeat a CP 3000 Pokemon if the player is extremely skillful, then it may make more sense... otherwise, just keep playing a few times and you can kick it out... then it is too easy to kick out a high CP Pokemon

Comment: I think that having one strong pokémon is good for training gyms (because you can use only one to attack), so you can power up your gym and fill it with your pokémons with ease.

Answer (score 5):

A single Pokémon with high CP can be knocked out from a gym pretty easily even with a party of fairly weak Pokémon. But having multiple high CP in a gym makes HUGE difference. Imagine you have to fight a gym with 3-5 or more high CP Pokémon with the same bunch of weak Pokémon. If you can't take down more than one Pokémon per run, it will take a lot of time and potions (when you assault gyms on daily basis, potions will become a huge factor). Most players don't even attempt to capture a gym with multiple high CP Pokémon because it would take too much effort.

Long story short, high CP Pokémon will help you to hold gyms longer, but they have to be in larger amounts. Single Pokémon gyms won't last long no matter the CP.

Comment: ok, I have seen gyms with Prestige of 4000 or 6000, but then later on I saw some with 20,000 or 45,000 (level 8 or 9).  Those will probably take forever if you need to kick out all Pokemons there... and I suppose the rule is, if you stay for 21 hours, then you can collect Defender Bonus? (but you have to claim it; it is not automatic?)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 It doesn't take hours. I watched in real-time my level 9 gym destroyed in 45-min... The attackers have the advantages. First, you do recon to see who the defenders are and their sequencing. Next, look at your pokedex to see what gets you best *type advantage*. Estimate if you have enough potion to finish the job. Larger gyms are funner because you form a posse. There is a shared goal, yet each person wants to conserve his personal resources. Basically, defeating gyms requires thinking and preparation.  Defending gyms... nothing you can do.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 It isn't automatic. When you collect the defender bonus for the first time, you start a counter and from that moment you can manually collect the bonus every 21 hours. Regarding the gym defense, it also depends on how contested the gym is. For example, I'm currently holding few gyms in rural areas for 8 days straight.

Answer (score 4):

What's the advantage of having a 2000 CP Pokemon? A player with 700 CP Pokemon could eventually knock you out of the Gym? Or a team of people with 400 CP Pokemon?

Your logic could be applied to all CP levels, and we just adjust the people attacking.

The **advantage** is that there are **less** people with higher CP Pokemon to be able to take down your 3000 CP. There are **less** teams of people with higher CP Pokemon to attack that Gym.

Sure it's possible, relatively easy actually if you have the time (or a team) and the Gym is undefended. But it's the same for 2500 CP, 2000 CP, 1500 CP, 1000 CP Pokemon.

Answer (score 1):

1. The pokemon with the highest CP will bubble to the top and be the last to get kicked-out. For example, even if you are the 7th one to enter a gym, if your CP is highest, you get kicked-out last.
2. To *attack* a gym, you can repeatedly go 6 against 1 and chop the gym down slowly. To *enter* a gym, it is 1 on 1. And, your 1 must be very powerful because your gym mates will use very high CP pokemon because of issue #1 above.

Comment: `your 1 must be very powerful ` unless your gym mates use the "magikarp technique" of putting one very low CP pokemon (e.g. a 10CP magikarp) to make it easy for team mates to increase the gym level.